# Python Pandas update value in row using precedent row value

Tags: python, pandas, diff, shift

I have to use precedent row value to calculate new value. 
I have a lot of rows, i don't want to use loop because it takes a lot of time, i tried with shift but i think it doesn't help me or i probably don't know how to use it.

here, little example about what i want to do.

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4,2,3,2], 'B': [2, 3,4,5]})  
In [273]: df                                                                                   
Out[273]:  
   A  B   
0  4  2  
1  2  3  
2  3  4 
3  2  5
```

I want to create new column 'C':

- First value of C is first value of A
- Second value of C, takes first value of C and add B (second),
- Third value of C, takes second value of C and add B (third) To get something like (final result)

`In [273]: df                                                                                   
Out[273]: 
   A  B    C
0  4  2  4.0
1  2  3  7.0
2  3  4  11.0
3  2  5  16.0`

I really dont want to use loop or apply so if there is another fast way i really want to know it.

Thank you very much

Comment: When you change your question , you should inform each single answers, since we already answered the question. If not , you will see the post like  ansev under my answer , and the downvote of our answers

Comment: And question rolled back, please ask a new question for the totally different issue.

Comment: Sorry, when I’ve changed the question stack proposed me to put why, I thought they will send messages to all answers, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a cumulative division, so the inverse of a cumulative prod method, you can get it with `.cumprod()` method.

The only trick is you want to start with the first value of column A instead or B so you need to multiply by the first value of A and by the first value of B

```
df['C'] =  1/df['B'].cumprod()*df.loc[0,'B'] * df.loc[0,'A']

#   A   B   C
#0  4   2   4.000000
#1  2   3   1.333333
#2  3   4   0.333333
#3  2   5   0.066667
```

Comment: Actually my real formula is df[C] precedent / (1 + df[B]), so C should have = [4, 1, 1/5, ...]

Comment: @Náthali I have updated my answer. Basically the sums have become products and the  substractions divisions

Answer (score 1):

To add to the existing answers: if efficiency is important, I think accumulate tends to be faster (although it adds another dependency):

```
from itertools import accumulate
df['C'] = df['A'].values[0] + list(accumulate(np.append(0, df['B'].values[1:])))
```

Comment: this is not what OP is looking for

Comment: The question was different at the time of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) + [`Series.cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html) 
to get the cumulative division:

```
df['C']=df['A'].where(df.index==0, 1/df['B']).cumprod()
print(df)

   A  B         C
0  4  2  4.000000
1  2  3  1.333333
2  3  4  0.333333
3  2  5  0.066667
```